# How to modify different values with same tags in XML using Python?

Tags: python, xml

I try to do this thing here :

## BEFORE

```xml
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d>
                <name>VERSION</name>
                <description />
                <defaultValue>v1.0.0</defaultValue>
                <trim>false</trim>
            </d>
            <d>
                <name>LINK</name>
                <description />
                <defaultValue>current</defaultValue>
                <trim>false</trim>
            </d>
        </c>
    <b>
</a>
```

## AFTER

```xml
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d>
                <name>VERSION</name>
                <description />
                <defaultValue>v2.0.0</defaultValue>
                <trim>false</trim>
            </d>
            <d>
                <name>LINK</name>
                <description />
                <defaultValue>I changed the link</defaultValue>
                <trim>false</trim>
            </d>
        </c>
    <b>
</a>
```

I have an XML file and I want to change the default values.
I tried with this code but didn't work and idk how to handle it :

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tab = ["V2.0.0, "I changed the link"]
i = 0
tree = ET.parse("myfile.xml")
for child in tree.findall(".//d"):
    tree.find(".//defaultValue").text = tab[i]
    i=+1
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
tree.find(".//defaultValue").text = tab[i]
```

with

```
child.find(".//defaultValue").text = tab[i]
```

Add this line of code as the last line of your script in order to see the modified XML

```
ET.dump(tree)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I was so close lol ... but it is working for me !! So thank you